# MAAS in VMware Workstation Environment to Boot VM Guests

Tags: maas, ipmi

Installed and Configured MAAS. I was able to successfully deploy Ubuntu as VM Guest. However, once deployed, VM Guest (Ubuntu), in about 10 - 15 seconds, powers itself off complaining on IPMI.

Errors:

> Starting IPMI event daemon Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
>
> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ipmi_si' No such device

Now, I did configure Power type based on MAAS documentation. However, I am not clear if libvirt-bin needs to be installed on VM Guest or on MAAS server? If on VMGuest, it is not staying up long enough to get package + ssh keys installed (gets powered off in 10-15 sec after the boot, complaining on IPMI).

Answer (score 0):

libvert-bin would need to be installed on the maws-controller. libvirt uses soap api calls to the ESXi server to power on the host. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe if your setup is moving VMs around on various esxi hosts, then libvirt won't cut it.